# a simple Chapter heading style

Tags: sectioning, chapters, exercises

I would like to create the chapter and exercise style using on the following book

**[Foundations of Analysis, Joseph L. Taylor University of Utah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821889842)**

- Chapter heading style
- Exercise style

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[hmargin=0.5in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Sequence}
        In this chapter we have our first encounter with the concept of limit the
concept that lies at the heart of the calculus. We first study limits of sequences
of real numbers. Limits of functions will be studied in the next chapter.
\section{Limits of Sequences}
Limits make sense in any context in which we have a notion of distance between
objects. Thus, we begin with a discussion of the notion of distance between two
real numbers.\\

\hrule\hrule\setlength{\parindent}{100ex}
\textbf{\large Exercise set }  
\\
    Make an educated guess as to what the limits are for the
following sequences.
\begin{itemize}
\item ${\displaystyle \left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}  }$
\item ${\displaystyle  \left\{\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right\}  }$
\item ${\displaystyle  \left\{(-1)^{n}\right\}  }$
\item ${\displaystyle  \left\{\sqrt{4+\dfrac{1}{n}}\right\}  }$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting with [titlesec](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package. Here's a quick example that shows something similar to what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[hmargin=0.5in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Customize chapter style
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\large\flushright} % format
{\titlerule[2pt]%
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
\vspace{0.1in}\textit{\chaptertitlename \thechapter}} % label
{1in} % separation
{
    \LARGE \flushleft 
} % before-code
[
] % after-code

% Customize chapter style
\titleformat
{\paragraph} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\large\flushright} % format
{
} % label
{1in} % separation
{
    \titlerule[2pt]%
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE \flushright 
} % before-code
[
] % after-code

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Sequence}
    In this chapter we have our first encounter with the concept of limit the
    concept that lies at the heart of the calculus. We first study limits of sequences
    of real numbers. Limits of functions will be studied in the next chapter.
    \section{Limits of Sequences}
    Limits make sense in any context in which we have a notion of distance between
    objects. Thus, we begin with a discussion of the notion of distance between two
    real numbers.\\

    \paragraph{Exercise set}
    Make an educated guess as to what the limits are for the
    following sequences.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ${\displaystyle \left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}  }$
        \item ${\displaystyle  \left\{\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right\}  }$
        \item ${\displaystyle  \left\{(-1)^{n}\right\}  }$
        \item ${\displaystyle  \left\{\sqrt{4+\dfrac{1}{n}}\right\}  }$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i'm sure that there is at least someone here that could do it easly .